# Laravel: Eliminar registros de Relación muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de eliminar un dato de una relacion muchos a muchos, la idea es que según el producto, tiene registrada materia prima, pero ante la situación de un error en la materia prima registrada, el usuario pueda eliminarlo, a lo que no se como realizar esta accion, les muestro como tengo la vista, los modelos de la relacion, las rutas y como estoy tratando de eliminarlo pero no encuentro como hacerlo.

ESTOS SON LOS MODELOS

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Producto";
    protected $fillable = ['codigo', 'nombre', 'presentacion','precio_out','cantidad', 'foto'];

    public function materiaPrima()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MateriaPrima::class, 'itemProducto','producto_id','materiaPrima_id')->withPivot('min_produccion');
    }


<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;


class MateriaPrima extends Model
{
    protected $table = "MateriaPrima";
    protected $fillable = ['codigo', 'nombre', 'unit','precio_in','cantidad', 'foto'];

    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class);
    }
```

la vista esta definida de la siguiente forma:

```
 @foreach($datas as $producto)
                            @foreach($producto->materiaPrima as $materiaPrima)
                            <tr>
                            <td>{{$materiaPrima->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$materiaPrima->codigo}}</td>
                            <td>{{$materiaPrima->nombre}}</td>
                            <td>{{$materiaPrima->cantidad}}</td>
                            <td>{{$materiaPrima->pivot->min_produccion}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="{{route('eliminar_matPriProducto', ['id' => $materiaPrima->id])}}" class="d-inline form-eliminar" method="POST">
                                    @csrf @method("delete")
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-accion-tabla eliminar tooltipsC" title="Eliminar este registro">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    @endforeach
```

esta es la ruta que uso

```
Route::delete('producto/MatPrim/{id}', 'ProductoController@eliminarMateriaPrima')->name('eliminar_matPriProducto')->middleware('auth');;
```

No estoy seguro realmente de como realizar esa eliminacion en la relacion, es la primera vez que intento realizar este tipo de acciones con relaciones muchos a muchos.

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios:

- Si hablamos de una relación de muchos a muchos, entonces hace más sentido que tú relación sea en plural así:

  ```
  public function materiasPrimas()
  ```

Ahora para lograr eliminar de un producto una materia prima asociada debemos:

- Obtener el ID del producto y buscar el modelo asociado a este
- Al objeto producto indicarle acceda a la relación `materiasPrimas()`
- Ahora que acceda al método `detach` donde pasaremos el ID de la materia prima que obtenemos

Más o menos así:

```
$productoId = Producto::findOrFail($idProducto);

$productoId->materiasPrimas()->detach($id);
```

Dónde:

- `$idProducto` es el ID del producto que queremos desvincular de una materia prima
- `$id` es el ID de la materia prima que envías

**Referencia**

- [Attaching y detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)

Comment: Si quisiera eliminar tambien el producto, se podria hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias, logre solucionarlo de la siguiente forma en la vista cree esto:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="producto_id" value="{{$producto->id}}" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="materiaPrima_id" value="{{$materiaPrima->id}}" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="min_produccion" value="{{$materiaPrima->pivot->min_produccion}}" />,
```

Luego cree el controlador tomando con puros request esos datos y haciendo un detach de la siguiente forma no es muy practico pero me funciono:

```
 public function eliminarMateriaPrima(Request $request) {
 $producto_id=$request->producto_id;
 $materiaPrima_id=$request->materiaPrima_id; 
 $min_produccion=array('min_produccion'=>request('min_produccion'));
 $producto = Producto::findOrFail($producto_id);
 $producto->materiaPrima()->detach($materiaPrima_id,$min_produccion); 
 return redirect()->action('ProductoController@show', $producto_id); }
```